# Difference between Friedman for 3 levels or 3 Wilcoxon Signed Rank?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, friedman-test

I have 13 subjects all who completed 3 different warm-up protocols. I want to compare the results of their countermovement jump height test results after each warm-up. My data is not normally distributed. Is there a difference between conducting a Friedman test and post hoc test to see where the difference lies or conducting threeWilcoxon Signed Rank tests between each warm-up to see where the differences lie ?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. Friedman test is _not_ the [direct extension](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83907/3277) of the Wilcoxon test (in a manner like ANOVA is the extension of t-test or Kruskal -Wallis is the extension of Mann-Whitney). Friedman test has its own post-hoc pairwise comparison procedure invented.

Comment: I think the sign test is the paired test that corresponds to the Friedman.