# Friedman test_multiplicity

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test, multiplicity

I'm performing Friedman test to see if there is a difference between 8 treatments, then if it is significant I'll do Wilcoxon signed rank test to see which pair is significant. I wonder if I should adjust this for multiplicity or this isn't needed because it will be performed only if Friedman test is significant at 5% level. Please help.

Comment: Please note that Friedman analysis is [not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83907/3277) an extension of Wilcoxon from 2 to k groups. You should use either Quade analysis or perform the Sign test after Friedman.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplicity"? Is it about the multiple comparison correction?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, by multiplicity I meant if I should adjust alpha level due to multiple comparisons performed using wilcoxon test for each pair